# Can you break up your own full set when playing a Forced Deal?

Tags: monopoly-deal

If all you have is one complete, unbreakable set, can you play a forced deal? The question is whether your own forced deal can be used on your own set, since the card just says: "Swap any property with another player. (Cannot be part of a full set.)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The card text, as you quote, does indeed unambiguously prohibit trading away a card from your own full set, yes.

You might conjecture that this was not intended, but as it stands (with no errata or contrary ruling from an official source), card text prohibits the trade.

That said, Monopoly Deal is a lighter game, so I would certainly go with what feels right (obvious designer intent) over a strict adherence to card text. Just make sure that everyone at the table knows what the rule is and is happy with the change.

Comment: The question is based on the card text being ambiguous. It is clear that the other players property "Cannot be part of a full set" but the question is whether that applies to your property. After re-reading it, do you still think the card statement is well-formed and unambiguous?

Comment: Indeed, I re-read it several times before composing my answer. My instinct is to go with obvious intent, but card text simply doesn't support that, not even ambiguously. You have to actually add text (errata) to the card text to get it to apply only to the other player's card.

Comment: That said, Monopoloy Deal is light enough to accept your play group's enjoyment over the letter of the cards, so... (I've added a paragraph to my answer for this).